# Grails bean into spring bean

Tags: spring, grails

I'm trying to convert grails bean into spring bean

**Resources.groovy**

```
beans = {

    testLoggingUtils(com.test.logging.LoggingUtils) 
    {

    bean -> bean.factoryMethod = "getInstance"

    }
    trackLogging(testLoggingUtils: "getLogProcessorInstance")       

     }
```

I've converted above grails bean into

```
<bean id="testLoggingUtils" class="com.test.logging.LoggingUtils" 
 factory-method="getInstance"/>

<bean id="trackLogging" factory-bean="testLoggingUtils" 
       factory-method="getLogProcessorInstance"></bean>
```

This is the right way to do this? . Thanks for your help

Comment: It should be, yes - why?  If it didn't work, what was the error message?

Comment: In my application , I made many changes and this was one among them . and I got many error messages and i got confused . Thanks for the clarification